# Setting up WoWLAN with tcp (config file issue)

Tags: wireless-networking, wake-on-lan

I am trying to wake up my 3d-printing server via WoWLAN on specific events, e.g. an incomming ssh connection or a connection to the printing host-sw.

The machine is running on Ubuntu 18.04 with a 4.15.0-54-generic kernel. The wireless hw is an Intel Dualband-Wireless-AC 7260 device.

`iw list` says, supported WoWLAN methods include disconnect, magic packet, pattern match, GTK rekey, EAP identity req, 4-way handshake, rfkill release, network detection and TCP connection.

I could successfully activate the magic packet method through `#: iw phy0 wowlan enable magic-packet` and waking up the system with this method works fine.

However, I can't get the TCP method working. Just running `#: iw phy0 wowlan enable tcp` says, tcp needs to be specified in a config file:

```
Usage: iw [options] phy <phyname> wowlan enable [...] [tcp <config-file>]

[...]

The TCP configuration file contains:
  source=ip[:port]
  dest=ip:port@mac
  data=<hex data packet>
  data.interval=seconds
  [wake=<hex packet with masked out bytes indicated by '-'>]
  [data.seq=len,offset[,start]]
  [data.tok=len,offset,<token stream>]
```

So I wrote a config file (called 'wotcp'):

```
source=192.168.168.20
dest=192.168.168.39:22@48:53:B8:18:FC:86
data=00
data.interval=1
```

calling `#: iw phy0 wowlan enable tcp ./wotcp` 
results in `command failed: Invalid argument (-22)`. Specifying the full path or just using the file gives the same result.
I also tried different different values for data and data.interval but every time it says 'invalid argument'.

I tried to find out if I was using a wrong syntax by looking into https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jberg/iw.git/tree/wowlan.c?h=v4.14 but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. All specified values seem to be in the correct syntax

Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with my config file? Or does anybody have a valid and working config file and is willing to share it?

Thanks in advance!